# Selecting one column multiple times from a single table with different values

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a question as I am stuck on one of the sql queries that I have.
I have wrote this sql query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date(createddate) as Date,
       (SELECT maxage FROM wob_stock_age 
        WHERE (maxage = a.maxage) AND (totetype='B') 
        GROUP BY Date)AS Blue,

       (SELECT maxage FROM wob_stock_age 
        WHERE (maxage = a.maxage) AND (totetype='V') 
        GROUP BY Date)AS Yellow,

       (SELECT maxage FROM wob_stock_age 
        WHERE (maxage = a.maxage) AND (totetype='N') 
        GROUP BY Date)AS Pink
FROM wob_stock_age as a
```

As you can see I am selecting the same column multiple times under a different alias. However the result is not what I am expecting as I get Null values.

[image]

**UPDATED:** Actually i wanted to get one row for each date and want to get all the "totetype" PINK, BLUE and YELLOW in one row for one date. Instead of 3 rows for one date.

So the outcome would be

```
    |Date       |Blue|Yellow|Pink|
    ------------------------------
    |2016-02-16 |153 |27    |40  |
    ------------------------------
    |2016-02-17 |152 |26    |40  |
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Your query produces one column but your desired results have three.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MySQL and this is why the outer apply doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  Your question is unclear, but my best guess on what you are trying to do is:

```
SELECT maxage,
       SUM(CASE WHEN totetype = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Blue,
       SUM(CASE WHEN totetype = 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yellow,
       SUM(CASE WHEN totetype = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Pink
FROM wob_stock_age as a
GROUP BY maxage
ORDER BY maxage ;
```

Comment: right, i assume same. he wants to get the sum of three columns with one date and in single record.. +1

Comment: Thank you I had to do slight changes and the code works !

Answer (score 2):

Use `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date(createddate) as [Date],
  BlueTable.Blue,
  YellowTable.Yellow,
  PinkTable.Pink 
 FROM wob_stock_age as a
 OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT maxage as Blue
   FROM wob_stock_age 
   WHERE (maxage = a.maxage) AND (totetype='B') 
   --GROUP BY Date
 )BlueTable
 OUTER APPLY
 (
  SELECT maxage as Yellow
  FROM wob_stock_age 
  WHERE (maxage = a.maxage) AND (totetype='V') 
  --GROUP BY Date
 )YellowTable
 OUTER APPLY(
 SELECT maxage AS Pink
  FROM wob_stock_age 
  WHERE (maxage = a.maxage) AND (totetype='N') 
 --GROUP BY Date
 )PinkTable
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using mysql and the outer apply it's not supported